# Why is my custom block template not being picked up?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I am working on a custom slider programmatically. I create a custom module (block_example) and make a block (BlockExample.php) and a twig file (blockexample.html.twig) and also a module file (block_example.module). I want to place some code in twig file and call it in block file.

This is build function from block file (BlockExample.php)

```
public function build() {

  $renderable = [
    '#theme' => 'blockexample',
  ];

  return $renderable;
}
```

This is (blockexample.html.twig) file code

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <h1>This is Title</h1>
  <p>Description Coming From Twig File</p>
</div>
```

This is (block_example.module) file code

```
function block_example_theme() {
  return [
    'block_example' => [
      'variables' => ['test_var' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Now main question is how to print twig file in BlockExample.php

Comment: Why do you want print twig file in BlockExample.php? It's not follow of drupal. In file BlockExample.php you already return a render array, so when you add block  in theme content in blockexample.html.twig will be display.

Comment: @Jonh – This is totally Drupal. Why build complex markup in a plugin's build function when you can pass all variables to a template and later have others be able to override the markup from their theme?

Comment: Muhammad, look: `'#theme' => 'blockexample',` and `return ['block_example' => [`. Do you see the difference? One comes with an underscore, and one doesn't. Fix the typo, flush caches a thousand times and tell us if it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The theme key you use in you build funtions should be the same with the one you are using in your hook_theme.

In that case you code should look like so

```
public function build() {

  $renderable = [
    '#theme' => 'block_example',
  ];

  return $renderable;
}
```

Keep in mind to avoid dashes in those values, since they are used for the template naming.

Best regards.